# How to play .ts files from local on android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, m3u8

I have .m3u8 file which contain path of .ts files. I am using this for playing the audio music. I have these files stored locally in my SDCard. How should i use them to play from local? 
I have multiple .ts files for one track. What path should I pprovide to the MediaPlayer class to play the track?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play those ts files, you can use a command to join them and play it like one ts file.

so open `CMD` starting from your ts files folder (by **shift+right click** on the folder) and run `copy /b *.ts Joined.ts` but make sure your files are named correctly in order, so if you sort them in explorer window by name you can see them in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

On the Android OS the easiest way to play .m3u8 Files is to use an APP like "File Xplorer" to spawn your Media Players and see which one will work.

Both "VLC" and "BS Player" can be opened from "File Xplorer" and will play the .m3u8 File; though you might want to edit it first to choose the best Stream.

Another solution to deal with .m3u8 Files is to convert them.

Whether it's the 'Main' .m3u8 or the second one (if there IS a second one you probably want it local; so download it also) I find that "Media Converter" will read the File and convert it to 'something' that "BS Player" can play (and *some* other Players can not).

Obtain 'MC' from here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AndroidA.MediaConverter